# Spring Boot + Swagger UI

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger-ui

We have REST API created in Spring Boot and secured by Spring Security. Swagger-UI is used for documenting the API. It works well.

Now we decided to create two user roles and allow each role specific access.

We have two roles:
role1, role2

Current situation:

```
/endpoint1 (secured only for role1)
/endpoint2 (secured only for role1)
/endpoint3 (can access both role1 and role2)
```

Securing endpoints works well by spring security @Secured annotation.

The problem is the documentation is generated in **one** swagger-ui.html file and both role1 and role2 can access it and see doc for all endpoints.

We would like each user role see only docs for it’s endpoints. So we have idea to separate swagger-ui.html docs somehow to two files because it is easy to configure spring security roles for different endpoints.

Something like this:

```
/a/swagger-ui.html:
/endpoint1
/endpoint2
/endpoint3
```

Accessible only for role1

And:

```
/b/swagger-ui.html:
/endpoint3
```

Accessible only for role2

Is it good idea? What do you think is the best practice to follow our scenario? If solution is to split swagger-ui to two files than how can we do that? Or any other solution?